# How i use Cython def (jupyter notebook) in python (python3.7) script?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, cython, python-3.7

Use Cython def (jupyter notebook) in python (python3.7) script?

I have Cython Def's (x10 faster python def's) in '`cython_def.ipynb`', like:

```
%load_ext Cython
```

&

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm as tqdm
from tqdm._tqdm_notebook import tqdm_notebook as tqdm_n

cimport cython
@cython.boundscheck(False)  # Deactivate bounds checking
@cython.wraparound(False)   # Deactivate negative indexing.

def get_size_end_c(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] x, np.float64_t h=1):
    cdef int len_last = x.__len__() - 1
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] return_x =  np.full(x.__len__(), np.nan, dtype=np.float64)
    #############################################
    # your code
    #############################################
    return return_x
```

I wanna run python script:

```
import numpy as np
import cython_def 
x = np.random.randint(100, size=100)
y = cython_def.get_size_end_c(x, 10)
```

Comment: See https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html

Comment: @ead tnx, it's good work!